# how to display running count of records in query

Tags: sql-server-2012, group-by, count

I am working on SQL SERVER 2012, and I have been trying to figure out how to include a running count of records in a group by statement. For example, the query would look something like:

SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, TRANSACTION_ID, COUNT
FROM TRANSACTIONS
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID, TRANSACTION_ID
ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID, TRANSACTION_ID

And the output would look something like:

10   100   1

10   108   2

10   125   3

10   140   4

12   102   1

12   103   2

12   138   3

15   135   1

I appreciate any advice on how to query this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use a [**window function**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) such as `ROW_NUMBER()` for this one like so:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, TRANSACTION_ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID ORDER BY TRANSACTION_ID) AS [Count] -- Running incremental count of rows / TRANSACTION_ID per CUSTOMER_ID
FROM TRANSACTIONS 
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID, TRANSACTION_ID 
ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID, TRANSACTION_ID
```

Comment: Assuming transaction_id is unique in transactions, the group by clause can be removed

Comment: @Lennart True I would hope that's the case with their schema. :) But anything's possible when it's not my schema lol.

Comment: Absolutely, more of a note for the OP. Hard to tell without ddl in the question

Comment: Thanks for the added comments about being able to remove the group by clause. Yes, ID's are always unique in my schema.